# How to reset a jQuery UI slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-slider

```
    <!-- dirty -->
    <head>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            values: [ 75, 300 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    });
    </script>

    </head>

    <div class="demo">

    <p>
        <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
        <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
    </p>

    <div id="slider-range"></div>

    </div>

    <button type="button" 
onclick='$("#slider-range").slider("value", $("#slider-range").slider("option", "min") );'>
Test
</button>
```

Clicking on the button does not reset the slider. Any clues?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For **Range Sliders** you need to use the method `.slider("values", index, value)` instead.

```
<script>
function resetSlider() {
  var $slider = $("#slider-range");
  $slider.slider("values", 0, initialMinimumValue);
  $slider.slider("values", 1, initialMaximumValue);
}
</script>
<button type="button" onclick='resetSlider();'>Test</button>
```

Answer (score 20):

### Not storing your original options / multiple slider reset

If you don't want to store your original value or you have multiple sliders try this:

```
// Reset the sliders to their original min/max values
$('.slider').each(function(){

  var options = $(this).slider( 'option' );

  $(this).slider( 'values', [ options.min, options.max ] );

});
```

In relation to your code see [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-montalcini-mjwgt).

Comment: Unlike the accepted answer, this answer animates BOTH handles back to their place, while the accepted answer for some reason only animates the Max handle to its place, and "JUMPS" back the Min handle.

Comment: @publicravi I added a demo to show you how to use this in your code.

Answer (score 5):

Check out my answer here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxf3a/1/)

```
$(function() {
    var options = 
        {
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            values: [ 75, 300 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            }
        };

        $( "#slider-range" ).slider(
            options
        );
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

    $("#button").click(function()
       {
           $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0, options.values[0]);  
           $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1, options.values[1] ); 
           $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + options.values[0] + " - $" + options.values[1] );           
       });
    });
```

Comment: Sorry! I chose Alexander's answer only based on chronological order.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 3):

You may try as

```
function PrimarySlider() {  
 $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            values: [ 75, 300 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    });

}
```

call the function `PrimarySlider();` whenever you need slider and reset by calling

```
function ResetPrimarySlider() {
   $( "#slider-range" ).slider("destroy");
   PrimarySlider();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You also can reset in one line of code (if you use the range option in slider)

```
$("#slider-range").slider("option", "values", [some_min_val, some_max_val]);
```